# how to add "did you mean" in nutch-lucene search engine

Tags: lucene, nutch

i am having problem of implementing this suggestion to my bangla search engine.
could anyone kindly help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (built using Lucene), it offers you this [functionality built-in](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-solr-update/).

To do this by yourself using Lucene would need considerable effort and knowledge of n-grams, string distances etc. So why reinvent the wheel, if solr does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the [contrib/spellchecker](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/contrib/spellchecker/) folder. I don't know that I would agree with Mikos that it takes "considerable effort" to set it up, but as with everything else in Lucene, it's easier to just use Solr.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of the Solr spellchecker, the last version is not fully stable and can provoke grave exceptions.

The ticket is open on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1630?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel